# How can I get the indices of the max values of a rank 3 tensorflow::Tensor using the c++ api?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen

Let's say I have a `Tensor t` which has shape `{3, 4, 5}`. I would like to find the max value of the first and second dimensions, so the result of this operation would be a matrix of shape `{5, 2}`.

So far I have tried to this by getting an `Eigen::Tensor` from the `tensorflow::Tensor` and using `maxCoeff` in a loop, so:

```
auto t_mapped = t.tensor<float, 3>();
Eigen::Matrix<float, 5, 2> maximums;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    MatrixXf::Index maxRow, maxCol;
    t_mapped.maxCoeff(&maxRow, &maxCol);
    maximums(i, 0) = maxRow;
    maximums(i, 1) = maxCol;
}
```

But this doesn't work because `t.tensor<float, 3>()` returns an `Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 3, 1, long>, 16, MakePointer>`, not an `Eigen::Tensor`. There doesn't appear to be much documentation on the `Eigen::TensorMap` class.

How can I either get an `Eigen::Tensor` out of the `Eigen::TensorMap` or do what I'm trying to do with the tensorflow API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not call `tf.argmax` with `axis=0`?

Comment: Wont that return the maximum element? Not the index of it?

Comment: argmax returns the indices, max returns the element